# Who are the people thanked by John Mulaney in the end credits?

Tags: credits

In his Netflix special *Baby J*, John Mulaney tells the story of his intervention and rehab. Of his intervention, he says there was "a good lineup" and also that it was way too many people; 4 would've sufficed instead of 12, lamenting how he would have to keep thanking those twelve for saving his life.

In the end credits, he thanks a list of people for saving his life (the numbering is mine):

1. Fred
2. Berk
3. Mike
4. Bill
5. Erica
6. Nick
7. Natasha
8. Joe
9. Cara
10. David
11. Seth
12. Kevin
13. Marika

Who are they?

He names Seth Meyers and Fred Armisen during the special, but who are the others? And were they all present and did he miscount?

Comment: I found [an article in _Men's Health](https://www.menshealth.com/entertainment/a43711034/john-mulaney-intervention-who-was-there/) that names 10 of them, but that still leaves me 3 short.

Comment: @SQB - I saw the same article. "*Mike Birbiglia, a comedian and old friend of Mulaney; Mike Berkowitz, Mulaney's agent; Marika Sawyer, a producer who worked with Mulaney both at Saturday Night Live and on his standup; and David Miner and Cara Masline, both executive producers on John Mulaney & The Sack Lunch Bunch."*" *Late night TV host Seth Meyers, Comedian and Big Mouth co-star Nick Kroll, SNL alum Fred Armisen, Barry star Bill Hader,  Poker Face and Russian Doll star Natasha Lyonne*

Comment: I agree with @ BCdot *and* @Valorum because it's on topic, but knowing who they are isn't a big deal (doesn't matter?). He *himself* chose to *not* name these persons, because they can be friends, but also nurse, therapist, therapy group buddy, anyone involved in the process and that need more privacy than public gratitude.

Comment: @Valorum and of course, those names in the article are educated guesses.